# Theme.MaterialComponents.Light theme from material library is broken?

Tags: android, material-design

I'm using material library on version 1.1.0.

First image are "Theme.MaterialComponents.Light" without any customization. i'm expecting light actionbar

Second image are "Theme.MaterialComponents.Light" with colorPrimary and colorPrimaryDark defined. actionbar now seams as expected but all other component are wrong

It seams that all components use colorPrimary instead of colorAccent or colorSecondary.

It appens on material library 1.0.0 and 1.1.0, but not on old AppCompat themes.

It's a bug or i missing somethings?

this is using directly `@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light`
[image: default]

this is using

```
<style name="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.App">
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark_material_light</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_material_light</item>
</style>
```

[image: color primary]

Comment: You should post for example the styles and colors used in you app theme.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti edited with styles

Comment: For example the `TextInputLayout` uses the `Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox` style.  It uses as stroke `colorPrimary` on focused state and `colorOnSurface` on normal state.

Comment: yes that is the problem, on AppCompat TextInputLayout on focus state use colorAccent. the massive usage of colorprimary make Theme.MaterialComponents.Light "broken"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the "ipotetical bug" of material library i done an override of actionbar theme like this. it works but seams not much elegant

```
<style name="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.App">
    <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Light.ActionBar.Solid.App</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">#any</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.MaterialComponents.Light.ActionBar.Solid.App">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_material_light</item>
</style>
```